# Fetching array data in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I have fetched the JSON data using the following code.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139'); 
$data = json_decode($json,true);

print_r($data);
foreach($data as $key => $datas){
$datas[$key];
   }
```

this is the decoded json

```
   Array(
[coord] => Array
    (
        [lon] => 139
        [lat] => 35
    )

[sys] => Array
    (
        [message] => 0.0053
        [country] => JP
        [sunrise] => 1394571511
        [sunset] => 1394614136
    )

[weather] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 802
                [main] => Clouds
                [description] => scattered clouds
                [icon] => 03d
            )

    )

[base] => cmc stations
[main] => Array
    (
        [temp] => 289.82
        [pressure] => 1013
        [temp_min] => 289.82
        [temp_max] => 289.82
        [humidity] => 30
    )

[wind] => Array
    (
        [speed] => 3.08
        [gust] => 8.74
        [deg] => 230
    )

[clouds] => Array
    (
        [all] => 48
    )

[dt] => 1394611401
[id] => 1851632
[name] => Shuzenji
[cod] => 200
)
```

Then I tried to display the data using the Foreach method, but I couldn't got it right.

Can someone please help me with this.......

Comment: Please give us some more Information. What did you expect and what happened?

Comment: please provide your `foreach` code as well..

Comment: what does `$json` show?

Comment: What is not right, it's an array and you could use foreach.

Comment: can you show text when you print array?

Comment: I Have updated the question with the array and code.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use the following examples to read your PHP array:

```
echo $data['coord']['lon'];
echo $data['coord']['lat'];
echo $data['sys']['message'];
echo $data['sys']['country'];
echo $data['sys']['sunrise'];
echo $data['sys']['sunset'];
.... And so on
```

Currently you receive:

```
Array
(
    [coord] => Array
        (
            [lon] => 139
            [lat] => 35
        )
[sys] => Array
    (
        [message] => 0.0422
        [country] => JP
        [sunrise] => 1394571511
        [sunset] => 1394614136
    )

[weather] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 802
                [main] => Clouds
                [description] => scattered clouds
                [icon] => 03d
            )

    )

[base] => cmc stations
[main] => Array
    (
        [temp] => 289.26
        [pressure] => 1013
        [temp_min] => 289.26
        [temp_max] => 289.26
        [humidity] => 30
    )

[wind] => Array
    (
        [speed] => 3.08
        [gust] => 8.74
        [deg] => 252
    )

[clouds] => Array
    (
        [all] => 48
    )

[dt] => 1394612300
[id] => 1851632
[name] => Shuzenji
[cod] => 200
```

)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to show all keys/values, try:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data));
foreach($iterator as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- $data consists of arrary within an array.
- So you need to parse it properly.
- Use nested Foreach.